# What is the difference between a map being linear in linear algebra and a map being linear representation in linear representation theory?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

What is the difference between a map being linear in linear algebra and a map being linear representation in linear representation theory?

I know from the answers at the back of the book that the following map:

$$(S(t)f)(x) = f (tx),$$  where $S: R \rightarrow S(V)$ and $V$ is the subspace of all polynomials with real coefficients and $t \in \mathbb{R}, f \in V.$

Is not a linear representation (but I do not know how?). Even though I found it is linear when I put instead of $f$, $\alpha f + \beta f$.  I know that for the given map to be a linear representation it must be a homomorphism (I am not very sure from this information, is it correct?) so what are the operations that I should consider here for studying homomorphism?

Could anyone clarify this discrepancies for me please?

Comment: What is $R$ in this case?  What is $S(V)$?

Comment: R is the reals .... S(V) the group  of  something(which I do not know) over the vector space V @Omnomnomnom

Comment: Which book are you using?

Comment: @user458276 "Linear Representations of groups" for Ernest B. Vinberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $t$, $S(t)$ is indeed a linear map; but $t\mapsto S(t)$ is not a morphism, because $S(t+t') \neq S(t)\circ S(t')$ in general.

If you consider $\mathbb{R}^*\to GL(\mathbb{R}[X])$, $t\mapsto S(t)$, it will, however be a morphism because $(S(tt')f )(x) = f(tt'x) = f(t\cdot (t'x))= S(t)f(t'x) = S(t)(S(t')f)(x) = (S(t)\circ S(t') (f))(x)$ so $S(tt') = S(t)\circ S(t')$.

A linear representation of a group $G$ is a morphism $G\to GL(V)$, that is, for each $g\in G$ you have a linear map $\rho_g : V\to V$ (subject to certain conditions). $\rho$ is a group morphism, $\rho_g$ is linear.

Here $S(t)$ is linear but $t\mapsto S(t)$ is not a group morphism from $(\mathbb{R},+)$

Comment: What is S(V) here and why $S(t + t^')$$  \neq  $$S(t) \circ S(t^')$, could you give me an example please?

Comment: Why "$S(t+t') \neq S(t)\circ S(t')$ in general" , could you give me an example please?

Comment: Please think about it and try to see what it would mean for $S(t+t')$ to be $S(t)\circ S(t')$. Pick almost any example of polynomial to see

Comment: okay thank you so much :)

Comment: but what is $S(V)$?

Comment: Can $S(V)$ be any group like the group of n x n invertible linear operators?

Comment: It's probably the group of invertible linear operatirs (but not $n\times n$ because $V$ is infinite dimensional)

Comment: Thank u so much your explanation was perfect :)

Comment: How do you create the example that turns our given function into homomorphism ? what was you trying to avoid to make given function homomorphism?